# google qpx with python3. HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, google-qpx-express-api

Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly here. I'm running python 3.5 on a macbook pro. Given this dictionary:

```
 data = {'request': {'passengers': {'adultCount': 2,
   'childCount': 0,
   'infantInLapCount': 0,
   'infantInSeatCount': 0,
   'seniorCount': 0},
  'refundable': 'false',
  'slice': [{'date': '2016-01-01',
    'destination': 'PMI',
    'maxStops': '0',
    'origin': 'ZRH'},
   {'date': '2016-01-10',
    'destination': 'ZRH',
    'maxStops': 0,
    'origin': 'PMI'}],
  'solutions': 50}}
```

so everything that should be quoted is quoted.

Now I do:

```
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key={API_KEY}".format(API_KEY = iOS_KEY)
```

where `iOS_KEY` is the `iOS` key I got from my API console. I'm not sure whether I have selected the right kind of KEY.

After this, I run:

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
binary_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode('utf-8')
myREQ = Request(url, binary_data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
urlopen(myREQ)
```

my stacktrace is:

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-167-aa1da44f3dff> in <module>()
----> 1 urlopen(myREQ)

/Users/eron/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    160     else:
    161         opener = _opener
--> 162     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    163 
    164 def install_opener(opener):

/Users/eron/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    469         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    470             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 471             response = meth(req, response)
    472 
    473         return response

/Users/eron/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    579         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    580             response = self.parent.error(
--> 581                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    582 
    583         return response

/Users/eron/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    507         if http_err:
    508             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 509             return self._call_chain(*args)
    510 
    511 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

/Users/eron/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    441         for handler in handlers:
    442             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 443             result = func(*args)
    444             if result is not None:
    445                 return result

/Users/eron/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    587 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    588     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 589         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    590 
    591 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Anybody faced a similar issue?

Comment: I'm doing an HTTP request via `urllib`, how could the API known it's python 3.5 underneath?

Comment: This code isn't being run on appengine. This question has nothing at all to do with appengine.